# Написать объект месяцев?

Tags: javascript

Как создать объект "Месяца" с ключами месяцев?

Пример:

```
var Mounthes = [
  Январь = пустой массив
  Февраль = пустой массив
  Март = пустой массив
]
```

Comment: `var Mounthes = {Январь: [], }`

Comment: нужно формула для каждого месяца. Это возможно?

Comment: `var Mounthes = {Январь: [], Февраль: [], Март: [], Апрель: [], Май: [], Июнь: [], Июль: [], Август: [], Сентябрь: [], Октябрь: [], Ноябрь: [], Декабрь: []};`

Comment: А где тут формула месяца???)

Comment: Что такое формула месяца?

Comment: типа new.Data.getMounth(index) где index - число месяца. Мне нужно пушать данные с инпута только в текущий месяц. Вот такой пример я Вам рассказал. Такая ситуация

Comment: Что такое типа new.Data.getMounth(index)?

Comment: Да. Вы правы но увы не понимаю как мне это крассиво реализовать

Comment: Реализовать что? До сих пор непонятно, что вам вообще нужно

Comment: Есть форма с данными которая ровна массиву arr{}
Пушать эти данные только в текущий месяц. Выводить данные всех  месяцов

Comment: Какая форма с данными? Что такое arr{}? Всё ещё не понятно абсолютно ничего

Comment: Представте 12 блоков - это ваших 12 месяцов. Виводить информацию только в текущем месяце. Я делаю так что пушать в ключ обьекта (Mounthes). 12 ключей = 12 месяцев. Каждый месяц = ключ. Пушать данные только в текущей месяц

Comment: Это называется "добавить" в объект данные по ключу... а не пушать. Первый раз вижу такую терминологию. А так `mounths[ключ].push(данные)`. Ну или `mounths[ключ]` и делайте с ним, что хотите. При условии, что `mounths = { "ключ" : [], "ключ": [] ... }`. Ну короче как andreymal написал выше.

Comment: Так возможно методом new Date() получить первый месяц года? ))))

Comment: Первый месяц года - январь, его можно и без `Date()` получить)) Если вы хотите полный список названий месяцев, то нет, составляется руками: `var arr=[
   'Январь',
   'Февраль',
   'Март',
   'Апрель',
   'Май',
   'Июнь',
   'Июль',
   'Август',
   'Сентябрь',
   'Ноябрь',
   'Декабрь',
];` ... и потом достается по номеру `arr[number - 1]`.

Comment: Задания в том что пушать в этот месяц данные. Это я и хочу реализовать

Comment: так а что мешает "пушать" в  месяц из объекта, предложенного andreymal ?

Comment: Вы задачу просто не поняли

Comment: "Вы задачу просто не поняли" -  ставлю за заявление хамское минус Вам.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вроде оно?

```js
const months = [
    {name: 'Янбарь', arr: []},
    {name: 'Фебраль', arr: []},
    {name: 'Мартб', arr: []},
    {name: 'Апрелб', arr: []},
    {name: 'Мамь', arr: []},
    {name: 'Еще какой-то месяц', arr: []},
    // итд
];

(()=>{
    const index = new Date().getMonth();
    console.log('Month no:', index+1);

    months[index].arr.push('something');
    months[index].arr.push('something2', {and: 'me'});

    console.log(months[index].name, months[index].arr);
})();
```